# I need a React component with a tree component and a "contents" pane

Tags: reactjs

I apologize in advance, not sure that it's appropriate to ask this here.
I need a tree component in React, which will have a collapsible tree view on the left, and a text pane on the right. Every node in the tree may be selected. When a node is selected, its textual data should be displayed on the right.
Can anyone help?

The data comes from a JSON stored in a MongoDB table. Here's an example:

```
"counters" : {
   "name" : "Root",
   "contents" : "refs: 19256 / 19500\nallocated_bytes: 830306 / 839259\nallocations: 17845 / 18089",
   "children" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "uat.goodie.pl_6740764444443739682",
            "contents" : "escalator: 2829\nevents: 10414\n[!] unknown URL alert (pe): 946 / 946",
            "children" : [ 
                 {
                     "name" : "pl_-5897027467868114979",
                     "contents" : "HTTP application\nTotal sessions: 0\nevents: 10414 \ne_events: 2829",
                     "children" : [],
                 }
             ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: What does your component structure look like? Where are you getting your data from, is it static text that will always be the same?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to hold an example of the data. The data is dynamic and comes from a JSON object stored in a MongoDB table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing some more, I decided to create a JSFiddle with this, I'm not that familiar with babel, so the syntax is a little different since I'm extending the react component, but here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/lDJamesl/8bkzu5or/1/

The code itself is:

```js
let contentJson = {
  "counters" : {
     "name" : "Root",
     "contents" : "This is content for root",
     "children" : [ 
          {
              "name" : "Child 1",
              "contents" : "Content for Child 1 or Root",
              "children" : [ 
                   {
                       "name" : "Grand Child 1",
                       "contents" : "Content for Grand Child 1",
                       "children" : [],
                   },
                   {
                       "name" : "Grand Child 2",
                       "contents" : "Content for Grand Child 2",
                       "children" : [
                             {
                               "name" : "Great Grand Child 1",
                               "contents" : "Content for Great Grand Child 1",
                               "children" : [],
                           },
                           {
                               "name" : "Great Grand Child 2",
                               "contents" : "Content for Great Grand Child 2",
                               "children" : [],
                           }
                       ],
                   }
               ],
          },
          {
              "name" : "Child 2",
              "contents" : "Content for Child 2 or Root",
              "children" : [ 
                   {
                       "name" : "Grand Child 3",
                       "contents" : "Content for Grand Child 3",
                       "children" : [],
                   },
                   {
                       "name" : "Grand Child 4",
                       "contents" : "Content for Grand Child 4",
                       "children" : [],
                   }
               ],
          }
      ],
  }
};

class TreeComponent extends React.Component{  
    constructor(props){    
    super(props);
    
    this.onSelectTreeElement = this.onSelectTreeElement.bind(this);
    this.getChildrenElements = this.getChildrenElements.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectTreeElement(){
    this.props.onSelectTreeElement(this.props.treeComponent);
  }
  
  getChildrenElements(){
    let self = this;
    let children = [];
    
    this.props.treeComponent.children.forEach((treeElement) => {
        let treeComponent = <TreeComponent         
        treeComponent={treeElement}        
        onSelectTreeElement={self.props.onSelectTreeElement}
      />;      
      children.push(treeComponent);
    });
    
    return children;
  }

  render(){       
    return (
      <div className='tree-componnet'>
      <h2 onClick={this.onSelectTreeElement}>{this.props.treeComponent.name}</h2>
        <div class='child-components'>
          {this.getChildrenElements()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class MainComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      SelectedElement : null
    };
    
    this.onSelectTreeElement = this.onSelectTreeElement.bind(this);
  }
  
  onSelectTreeElement(treeElement){
      this.setState({SelectedElement : treeElement});
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="elements-container">      
        <div className='tree-list-elements'>
          <TreeComponent            
            treeComponent={this.props.contentJson.counters}             
            onSelectTreeElement={this.onSelectTreeElement}
          />
        </div>
        
        <div className='component-display'>
          {this.state.SelectedElement != null ? 
            <div>
              <p>{this.state.SelectedElement.contents}</p>
            </div>
            :
            <div>
              <p>No element selected</p>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
  }  
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <MainComponent contentJson={contentJson}/>
      </div>      
    );
  }
}

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

render();
```

```css
.tree-componnet {
    padding-left: 1em;    
}

.tree-componnet h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: .2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tree-list-elements {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.component-display {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.9/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.9/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">Test</div>
```

Comment: I've really tried this, but did not find a way to overcome: when I click on a node, the onSelectTreeElement function is called for the element, its parent and its parent up to the root, so the selected element is always the root. Can you please assist?  How do I make the onSelect... for children not be invoked for the parent too?

Comment: Hey @Shimon, I updated the code with a working example. I hope this gives you a better idea. If you still have issues, I would suggest to upload your code to gitHub or something like that and we might be able to give you a hand.

Comment: Also, I just read again your comment, the problem with this is that the onClick function was on the entire element, when it should've been on the Name/title only.